# The degree of a map between complex projective lines

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, projective-space

Let $P$ and $Q$ be complex polynomials such that $\deg P=p$, $\deg Q=q$ and $\gcd(P,Q)=1$.

How can I:

- show that $F(z)=\frac{P(z)}{Q(z)}$ defines a smooth map $\mathbb{C}P^1\to\mathbb{C}P^1$?
- compute a degree of $F$?

Comment: $F$ is a meromorphic function on all of $\mathbb{C}P^1$. Thus it is a holomorphic map $\mathbb{C}P^1\to \mathbb{C}P^1$. To find the degree: how many zeros and how many poles (counting multiplicity) does $F$ have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can homogeneize the map: write $P(z)=\sum_{i=0}^p a_i z^i$, $Q(z)=\sum_{i=0}^q b_i z_i$, $d=\max\{p,q\}$ and define
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\mathbb{P}^1&\to & \mathbb{P}^1\\
[z:w]&\mapsto & [\sum_{i=0}^p a_i z^iw^{d-i}:\sum_{i=0}^q b_i z^iw^{d-i}]
\end{array}$$
This is a holomorphic map from $\mathbb{P}^1$ (or $\mathbb{C}P^1$) to itself and which restricts to your map on the subset where $w=1$. The degree is equal to $d$.